# Showing both selected Dimensions in the MDX query result?

Tags: mdx, dimensions

How can I get the MDX query below to display the date next to the customer? Currently it only displays the customer, or whichever dimension I make first in the nonempty call. I'd like both to show in the results.

```
SELECT  {[Measures].[Count1], [Measures].[Count2], 
  [Measures].[Count3]} ON COLUMNS,                               
nonempty({[Customers]}, {[DateRange]}) ON Rows                 
FROM Cube
```

I tried crossjoin but that return an out of memory error.

Thanks!

I am getting this:
    **Customer | Count1 | Count2 | Count3 |**

I would like to see this:
    **Customer | Date | Count1 | Count2 | Count3 |**

Comment: Can you add some sample output of what you are getting and what you would like to see?

Comment: Thanks! I have updated the question with what i get and I what I need to get.

Answer (score 0):

Generally a measure goes as the second argument of NONEMPTY

```
SELECT  {[Measures].[Count1], [Measures].[Count2], 
[Measures].[Count3]} ON COLUMNS,                               
nonempty(({[Customers]}, {[DateRange]}),{[Measures].[Count1], [Measures].[Count2], 
[Measures].[Count3]}) ON Rows                 
FROM Cube
```

I put all three measures as part of the set for the `NonEmpty` function.  This would return data where any row has at least one of the three counts that isn't null.  It only filters out rows that are null for all three counts.